# Apply css class to the first cell in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-class with ng-repeat, and trying to apply a class to my first cell. My first cell should have a red background. However, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="item">
           <td class="thing" ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-class="{thing-red: $first}"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>

.thing-red {
    background:red;
}
```

This works as expected (all cells are red):

```
<td class="thing thing-red" ng-repeat="thing in things"></td>
```

Comment: Does wrapping thing-red in quotes have an effect? ie `ng-class="{'thing-red': $first}"`

Comment: It does! Why didn't I try that :)

Comment: Yeah I think it has to do with the implementation of `ng-class`. The rule of thumb that has guided me here is to only use class names that are valid object keys. I think that's the difference between when you need quotes and when you don't.

Comment: What are valid object keys?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
<td class="thing" ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-class="{'thing-red': $index == 0}"></td>
```